# Is there locale-aware week of months in momentjs?

Tags: momentjs

Is there locale-aware week of months in momentjs? I see there is a `week()` which returns the week of year but I can't find a week of months that is localized.

Currently achieving this functionality using this helper function. This is basically what I need, so I was wondering if there is a better way:

```
function weekOfMonth(d){
    var firstDay=moment(d).date(1);
    return moment(d).isoWeek()-firstDay.isoWeek();
}
```

Comment: Localized in what way?  Can you provide an example of what input and output you're looking for?

Comment: I think what you have (or something like it) is the best you're going to get.

Comment: @MattJohnson I know there is a mechanism in javascript to extend an object with additional functions. Do you know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The momentjs plugin [moment-recur](https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur)  adds this functionality with the `moment().monthWeek()` method